# How to use different spring module (spring-data-redis) version in specific spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have a `Spring boot` project - its parent is `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.9.RELEASE`. I want to use the `spring-data-redis` with `2.2.0.RELEASE` version (not the `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` because this does not support `redis-streams`). Also I use `Lettuce` version `io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.2.0.RELEASE`.

My `pom.xml`

```
     <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I get the following error when run, though the application has no compilation errors.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

            org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.RedisRepositoryConfigurationExtension.createMappingConfigBeanDef(RedisRepositoryConfigurationExtension.java:168)

The following method did not exist:

org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.getRequiredAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.11.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class

It was loaded from the following location:

file:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.11.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource
```

The `spring-data-redis` is resolved to `2.1.11.release` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint given by Dirk Deyne (who deleted those comments?), the `spring-data-redis` version can be overriden with the expected version like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Having got other dependency issues because of this (error in question) specific version, have to add other libraries versions too, in this case

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```